# How do I charge .1 (one-tenth) of a cent per product purchased in Stripe?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm creating a pricing plan based on microservices, where for every service call I charge the user $0.001. Stripe only supports charging amounts in the cents, so how do I charge based on one tenth of a cent?

Ideally it would be something like:

```
stripe.Plan.create(
    nickname="product name",
    product="product id",
    currency="usd",
    interval="month",
    usage_type="metered",
    amount = .1
)
```

However, that throws an error since amount must be a positive integer (because otherwise you will have rounding errors).

Comment: Is it not possible to charge 1¢ per ten service calls instead?

Comment: use min() max() or float() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can use [usage transformation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/usage-transformation) to change the quantity before applying the total cost. So instead of charging .1 cents per call, I'm charging 1 cent per 10 calls.

```
stripe.Plan.create(
  nickname="Product name",
  product="{{PRODUCT_ID}}",
  currency="usd",
  interval="month",
  usage_type="metered",
  amount=1,
  transform_usage={
    "divide_by": 10,
    "round": up
  },
)
```

Comment: Won't this hide the charge from them though?

Comment: @alec_a It's a method that they provide, it doesn't hide anything from them.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you submit the usage record, the `quantity` attribute also needs to be an integer, so you'll need to scale that up as well.